# On Mac: Cannot run program /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" in directory... error=7, Argument list too long

Tags: java, macos, google-app-engine, gwt, java-6

I get the following error.

Cannot run program "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" (in directory "/Users/samschmid/Privat/dev/amsf/App-Management-System-Framework/App Management System"): error=7, Argument list too long
Cannot run program "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" (in directory "/Users/samschmid/Privat/dev/amsf/App-Management-System-Framework/App Management System"): error=7, Argument list too long

i search on google for 7 hours and no solution worked for me. Does anybody have a hint for me?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your project has a huge list of dependencies, so when gwt compiler or dev mode is launched, such a classpath generates a long command line.

Your problem is not related with java nor gwt, but with your OS limits.

Change the limits in your system. Take a look to this post:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/argument-list-too-long-error-solution/

Comment: Thank you! I already came across the arg_max. Is there no way to increase arg_max?

Comment: what shell are your running, type `echo $SHELL` in your terminal

Comment: bash... i start my program with the "too long argument list" from eclipse (Datanucleus enhancer)

Comment: i never tried to compile it from command-line. Do you know how i can compile it from command line? (GWT including DataNucleus enhancer)

Comment: do you have a build.xml or a pom.xml in your project root?